# How to call a function that returns another function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, closures

I was taking a small test online and there was this code:

```
function getFunc() {
    var a = 7;
    return function(b) {
        alert(a+b);
    }
}
var f = getFunc();
f(5);
```

I would like to know why I can't call `getFunct(5)` directly for example.

I don't understand the last two lines.

Why do I need to assign the function to a variable. What happens when doing f(5)?

How does JS interpret that the 5 is a variable for the inner function and not the outer?

Comment: Because that's not the definition of `getFunc`. `getFunc` *returns* a function you call with a parameter. Look at the signature of `getFunc`: is there a parameter?

Comment: `getFunc` **returns** a `function`. So, `f` is just the inner function where the contextual `a` is 7. You shouln't directly call it, because the call signature of `getFunc` just doesn't accept any argument, so calling it with any argument will do nothing.

Comment: @briosheje Well. You *could*, it just wouldn't work the way the OP wants it to.

Comment: @DaveNewton You're right, you technically _could_ indeed, but that would do nothing. However, that's right, you actually **can** do that, but it just won't do anything.

Comment: try: **var f = new getFunc();**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could call the inner function immediately after calling the first one, because the first call returns a function and the second call gives the result.

```js
function getFunc() {
    var a = 7;
    return function(b) {
        console.log(a + b);
    }
}

getFunc()(5);
```

Comment: _"I don't understand the last two lines. Why do I need to assign the function to a variable. What happens when doing f(5)? How does JS interpret that the 5 is a variable for the inner function and not the outer?"_

Comment: Yes, but I think the OP is asking *why* it is this way, not a way to eliminate the intermediate variable.

Comment: Yes @DaveNewton this is exactly what I needed. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

By assigning getFunc() to the variable f you actually assigned the return value i.e. inner function to f since that's what getFunc is returning. The braces () make a difference here.

However had it been f = getFunc i.e. without the braces, that would imply f is an alias for getFunc and you'd have to do f()(5) in that case.